# NLB NIC w/ Static IP permanently "Acquiring Network Address" after adding more IP's to the cluster

Tags: windows-server-2003, nic, drivers, windows-nlb

We have a 2 node NLB cluster. I recently added more IP's to the cluster range, after which point, the NLB NIC's on both of my nodes ended up in a permanent "acquiring network address" state.

The cluster appears to be functioning despite this hang in acquiring an address.

We've also rebooted the machines, and these NIC's remain in this state "acquiring network address" even after reboot, which I find troubling.

Questions:

1. Does anyone know where I can find documentation on how NLB binds to a NIC? (are there dll's involved, drivers, etc.)
2. Does anyone know of any programs that have known incompatability issues with NLB?

We have an application server installed on these NLB nodes (AOL Server) that interacts with the NIC's as well, and I suspect that it might be causing this issue. Before I go directly to Microsoft, I want to gather as much information as possible about the issue.

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated...